# May I connect to embedded mysql using Cloud9 free account?

Tags: mysql, cloud9-ide

As I try to connect to MySql using Cloud9 console I get `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`.

Is it possible to access MySql DB application for free accounts?

Comment: Do the articles at https://docs.c9.io/setup_a_database.html and https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html help? Free accounts only have limitations on RAM, CPU & disk space, but they're fully functional Linux containers (you even have sudo access).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql is actually running, by executing

```
echo -n "mysql is "; if ! ps -C mysqld > /dev/null; then echo -n "not "; fi; echo "running"
```

from the command prompt. If it is not running, start it using:

```
mysql-ctl start
```

When it runs, use following to connect:

```
mysql-ctl cli
```